# Python не видит библиотеку в venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, venv

Установил PyCharm. Создал проект с виртуальным окружением (venv). Через pip установил colorama. Но почему-то питон не видит эту библиотеку в venv'е. Как это можно поправить?

main.py:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

[image: Screenshot cmd]

Comment: python.exe .\main.py  не пробовали запустить?

Comment: @void, сработало. Спасибо
Почему я не могу просто написать в консоли: main.py?

Comment: у вас при запуске `main.py` вызывается глобальный питон который установлен у вас в `%appdata%` либо в по пути где у вас установлен питон т.е. используется глобальное окружение windows, а при вызове `python` он обращается уже к в виртуальному окружению

Comment: @Twiss Спасибо))